# unreachable statement with layout inflater

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I am trying to convert my layout into java object using **layoutInflater** but when i try to get a reference to `LayoutInflater` Class i get an error **"Statement unreachable"**

this is my code

```
package test.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

/**
 * Created by HADDAD on 12/8/13.
 */
public class TonyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
            Context context;
    public TonyAdapter(Context c, String[] titles) {
        super(c, R.layout.sinlge_row,R.id.textView , titles);
           this.context=c;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you return in the first line. Change your code to:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    // ... more code
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can not have code after `return`. Change it to something like:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(/** your layout.. */);
    return v;
}
```

Or just call it through super:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    // do something with v
    return v;
}
```

Depending on your use case.